# Playing mp3 with go on pi

Tags: raspbian, media

I am trying to play mp3 and wav files on the pi from a program written in go.

To date I have had no success. Does anybody have any simple working examples that
Have been tested on the pi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure about Go but if you can launch command line (hidden?) and keep it live while it does its thing then use `omxplayer`. Not only can it play back video do a specified screen, like HDMI it can also play audio files like MP3, AAC or WAVE.

```
apt-get install omxplayer
```

Sometimes its needed to do this.

```
ldconfig
ln -s /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libpcre.so /usr/lib/omxplayer/libpcre.so.1
```

Because omxplayer uses the hardware GPU its need GPU memory.

In the file `/boot/config.txt` , add the line `gpu_mem=128`  or set it using raspi-config

example to stream audio via HDMI

```
omxplayer -o hdmi Ten_Walls_-_Walking_With_Elephants.mp3
```

Comment: I ended up hacking some code which uses GStreamer which I am assured is far from optimal. However I have used OMXPlayer and agree that this is probably an easier way to go :-)

Comment: Awesome. Glad it helped you out, it was the easiest method I found that plays various formats without moaning and easily select the output too :)

Comment: rewrote it to use Omxplayer because the Gstreamer version did not allow cross compilation....
Thanks Again.